# Bug on mathematical expression verification

Tags: c, stack

I'm need to verify if ()[]{} of a mathematical expression are all closed.
Such {4 + 9} − (9 − 8) << are correct and ((()) aren't correct.
Using a stack builded using linked list.
Like if the actual index of the string have "{" or "[" or "(" push it to stack and if the index have ")" or "]" or "}" pop the top of stack and verify if are matching with the actual element. If stack are empty in the end, expression are correct, or if during execution loop the closing symbol don't match or stack isn't empty, the expression aren't correct.

**structs**

```
struct stack{char string[1];int index;struct stack *next;};

struct retpop{char string[1];struct stack *top;};
```

**functions pop/push**

```
struct stack *push(struct stack *topo, char *se){
struct stack *temp;

if (top == NULL)
{
    top =(struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack ));
    top->next= NULL;
    top->index = 0;
    top->string[0] = 0;
    snprintf(top->string, 1, "%c", se[0]);
}
else
{
    temp =(struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack ));
    temp->next = top;
    temp->index = top->index + 1;
    temp->string[0] = 0; 
    snprintf(temp->string, 1, "%c", se);
    top = temp;
}
return top;
}

struct retpop pop(struct stack *top){
struct retpop return1;

if (top == NULL)
{
    printf("EMPTY STACK\n");
    return;
}
else{
    struct stack *top1;
    top1 = top;
    snprintf(return1.string, 1, "%c", top1->string[0]);
    top1 = top1->next;
    free(top);
    top = top1;
}
retorno.top = top;

return return1;
}
```

**functions to analisis**

```
void process_string(char string[100]){

struct stack *top;
top = NULL;
int i = 0;

struct stack *temp;
int nullifier = 0;

char *temp;
struct retpop temppop;

while(i < (strlen(string)-1)){

    snprintf(temp, 1, "%c", string[i]);

    if(temp[0] == '}'){
        temppop = pop(top);
        top = temppop.top;
        if((char)temppop.string[0] != '{'){
            nullifier = 1;
        }
    }

    if(temp[0] == ']'){
        temppop = pop(top);
        top = temppop.top;
        if((char)temppop.string[0] != '['){
            nullifier = 1;
        }
    }
    if(temp[0] == ')'){
        temppop = pop(top);
        top = temppop.top;
        if((char)temppop.string[0] != '('){
            nullifier = 1;
        }
    }
    if(temp[0] == '{'){
        top = push(top,"{");
    }
    if(temp[0] == '['){
        top = push(top,"[");
    }
    if(temp[0] == '('){
        top = push(top,"(");
    }
    i++;
}

if((topo != NULL) || (anulador == 1)){
    printf("\nNOT VALID\n");
}
else{
    printf("\nVALID\n");
}
}
```

The problem are, the code correctly analise things like []{}()or [][][][][] but when i use {}{}{}{}{} or ()()()()() or {[()()()][()()()]} the stack return buggy values and the expression became false :/ What can I do? The problem are on my code?
(please ignore the use of stack inside the code, on my code i'm using the other word from my language, but to display in a better way i placed "stack" on code)

Comment: This is a simple program, where stack usage is required, but i feel you have unnecessarily complicated it.

Comment: So how can I simplify it? :/
That is the only way i found .-.

Comment: First of all you need not use two structures. Due to time constraint,I will be sending you links which suggests easier programs. 1st method using stack library http://www.lifengadget.com/lifengadget/program-to-check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/       2nd method - using a a single struture for stack http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-for-balanced-parentheses-in-an-expression/   The second link is the one you should be looking at, it is simple and has the efficiency of O(n).